# Insert PDF into CRM database with Web.API

Tags: c#, pdf, service, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have a C# Service generating a PDF document. After that I need to create a new record in CRM 2016 by using the Web-API and insert the generated PDF

Is this possible with the CRM Web-API? Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

Base64-encode the content and put it inside the `documentbody` field of an `annotation`. The correct MIME-type is `application/pdf`

Comment: hi alex, thank you for your quick reply :)

I will check wether I can store it in the annotation entity or if I need to store it somewhere else.

can you maybe give me a hint how to pass the encoded pdf to the web-api call?